# House address is not listed on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, address

When I search for my address on Google Maps it cannot be found which means I can't order takeaway etc.

Is there a way of adding my address to Google Maps or even add a street address?

I want the address to be publicly available so others can search it.

Comment: There is answer on Google Maps Help "Fix a missing address or wrong pin location" https://support.google.com/maps/answer/10010575

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [Google Maps help](http://support.google.com/maps) on how to [Fix an error on Google Maps](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=98014):

> Help us make Maps better
>
> Community edits allow you to modify the information you see on Google Maps, making it more accurate for everyone.
>
> To let us know about a point of interest other than a business, use the [Report a Problem](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=162873) link and follow these instructions:
>
> 1. Drag the marker to the position where the point of interest is located.
> 2. Under "Which element is wrong?", select "A place or landmark."
> 3. Under "Which place?", select "Place isn't listed."
> 4. Fill out the details under "Problem Description" and click **Report Problem**

Comment: I think the quoted text, which no longer appears on that page should be replaced by "To tell us a location is missing from Google Maps, learn how to [add a missing place](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6320846?)." which does.

Answer (score 4):

Someone in a similar situation to you posted here:

https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/maps/WJeY25YbFSo/n8hA_LZMEokJ

> 1. Go to Google.com
> 2. click on "About Google" at the bottom
> 3. click on "Contact us" at the bottom
> 4. At the first drop down box where it says *Or, jump straight to specific product contact options* - SELECT "Maps contact options"
> 5. Click on "Fix an error on Google Maps"
> 6. You can choose the option that best pertains to your situation, but if it's street name error click "Report incorrect map data"
> 7. (Tela Atlas provides Google Maps with their data) It says:  •Tele Atlas: Report a map error using their Map Insight system. Click on
>      "Map insight" link.
> 8. Click "English"
> 9. Click "Start"
> 10. click your country "United States" from the drop down box.
> 11. click your "state/province" from the drop down box.
> 12. Type in the address that needs corrected.  Click "search"
> 13. Click the green push pin marker to move it to the street you are describing.
> 14. Click "Step 2 - Describe"
> 15. Click "Address" icon
> 16. click "change and address, street name, house number or city"
> 17. Type the correct address
> 18. Click "additional remarks" to explain any information to help them understand the correction.
> 19. click "Step 3 - Submit"   - You will get an ID number with your request and an email stating that it has been completed.

Answer (score 1):

In the US you need a 911 address (Physical Address), this is usually calculated along a road segment. This is how car GPS units interpolate along the segment to find an address. Google also uses this method. Beyond Google, your local 911 center uses it to dispatch first responders to your location. So beyond pizza you should be more concerned if an ambulance or firetruck can find you. Just telling Google will only help if they are using Google. You may want to check with your county emergency services.

There is an association called National Emergency Numbering Assoc (NENA.org) that sets standards for addressing. So when you call 911 services can find you.